# Перечисление или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

"В большом(,) роскошном доме он чувствовал себя чужим" — тут нужна запятая или это не перечисление?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, в данном случае надо спрашивать не о перечислении, а о том, являются ли данные слова однородными определениями. Формально - нет, так как "большой" - это размер, а "роскошный" - это его качественная оценка, однако правила позволяют здесь поставить запятую, ибо в данном случае между слова имеется, хотя и незначительная, причинно-следственная связь (большой, поэтому роскошный). Розенталь пишет, что в таких случаях разные признаки могут быть объединены общим впечатлением, сходством по какому-либо объединяющему параметру. В данном случае таким объединяющим признаком является внешний вид дома.

Answer (score 0):

нет не перечисление.запятая не нужна

Answer (score 0):

Здесь запятая напрашивается. 
Но если рассуждать вообще, то пунктуация - по авторскому смыслу. Если, например, по контексту "большой роскошный" противопоставляется "маленькому роскошному" или "большому аскетичному" то запятой не требуется, эти определения не будет однородными. Если же это две взаимосвязанные характеристики действия дома на подсознание героя (а я полагаю, что здесь это именно так), то однородные, запятая нужна. 
Вообще понятие однородности-неоднородности зачастую отдаётся откууп субъективному ощущения автора, то что приводится у Розенталя - максимум верхушка айсберга, ибо общность "объединяющего признака" - вещь ещё более субъективная. Как и само наличие какого-либо признака. Всё только от смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, запятая весьма уместна, так как присутствует некая градация прилагательных *большой, роскошный*.